How to use a Commit as reference in Cursor IDE?
I have made a commit with some changes in users/create.vue file. I want to use that commit as reference/context in Cursor Composer so AI can see the changes I made in create.vue file, so I can ask the AI to apply same changes to the edit file users/[id].vue, since both files have similar code and structure.
There git option when you type @ in composer, and it shows commits as well, but AI response was :
I don't have direct access to the commit history or the changes made in "@create contact - tabs". However, based on the code I can see, it appears you're working with a tabbed interface for form fields.
